# Magento2: How to remove items from cart before adding new Item?

Tags: magento2, addtocart

I want to clear the cart before adding a new item to the cart.

I am trying to do using the event "`checkout_cart_product_add_before`" and by this code in the observer.

```
$allItems = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();

foreach ($allItems as $item) {
$itemId = $item->getItemId();
$this->cart->removeItem($itemId)->save();
}
```

My all items getting remove from the cart with the newly added item also.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can delete all item before they are adding as cart candidate. You can use following process

```
    $cart = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');

    foreach ($cart->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item) {
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item */
        $item->delete();
    }
    $cart->addProduct($newProduct, $request)->save();
```

Comment: Thanks, Its working fine.